git-submodule: bad variable name in nodejs project
This is likely the same problem as git-submodule: bad variable name, but with additional information provided in order to more easily solve the problem
$ git submodule summary
/usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule: 88: export: made.: bad variable name
* modules/example2 0000000...1945c42 (1):
  > Oops, uncomment

When debugging the error by adding set -x to /usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule, the following is output before the error happens:
... [cut]
+ eval_gettext usage: $dashless $USAGE
+ gettext usage: $dashless $USAGE
+ envsubst --variables usage: $dashless $USAGE
+ export PATH No variable replacements made.
/usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule: 88: export: made.: bad variable name

When I run envsubst directly, the following is output:
$ envsubst --variables 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
No variable replacements made.
$ which envsubst
/home/tno/repos/example/node_modules/.bin/envsubst
$ envsubst --version
0.15.0

My PATH is
$ echo $PATH
/home/tno/repos/example/node_modules/.bin:/home/tno/repos/example/bin:/home/tno/.local/bin:[cut]:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:[cut]


In case reviewers take a look at this, the reason I didn't edit the original question is because the original question didn't specify that the problem was happening within a node.js project.

BTW; this is not related to nodejs. A custom envsubst command is the root cause.

The problem is that git is trying to use the envsubst npm package instead of envsubst from the gettext GNU project. Try removing /home/tno/repos/example/node_modules/.bin from your PATH to see if it fixes the issue. A couple of other solutions are:

You can ensure that /usr/bin comes before /home/tno/repos/example/node_modules/bin in your PATH.

You can make a wrapper script around git that adjusts PATH before calling the real git. Make sure the wrapper's directory comes before /usr/bin in PATH. In your example, a few good places for putting this script would be ~/.local/bin/git, ~/repos/example/bin/git, or /usr/local/bin/git


#!/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH git "$@"

